# Test normality from histogram data

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, data-analysis

I have histogram data that I'd like to formally test for normality but I don't have the actual data points that generated the histogram.
The histogram looks something like this:

[image: histogram]

Is there a standard way to test normality in these cases?